# Load textext.js plugin with require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs, jquery-textext

I'm trying to load [textext.js](http://textextjs.com/) jquery plugin, with one of it's plugins, [textext tags](http://textextjs.com/manual/plugins/tags.html). On my project, I'm using require.js in order to load all scripts with it's dependencies.

As used for other scripts, I'm using a shim config on my `main.js` file:

**main.js**

```
require.config({
  shin: {
    jquery: {
      exports: '$'
    },
    'textext': {
      deps: ['jquery'],
      exports: '$.fn.textext'
    },
    'textext_tags': {
      deps: ['jquery', 'textext'],
    }
  },
  paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-min',
    textext: 'lib/textext/textext.core',
    textext_tags: 'lib/textext/textext.plugin.tags',
    }
  });
```

On the page that I use it, I call it as above:

**file-app.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'textext',
  'textext_tags',
  ], function($, Textext, TextextTags) {
    // do stuff
  });
```

The code is loading and working correctly on firefox, but on Chromium, sometimes (about 2/3 of the times), at the first time that I load the page, I've receive the following error, that broke the functioning of the page:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'TextExtTags' of undefined
   #3 localhost/js/lib/textext/textext.plugin.tags.js:23:27
```

Inside the file `textext.plugins.tags.js`, we have at line 23 (the failure line):

```
$.fn.textext.TextExtTags = TextExtTags;
```

So, inspecting it with Firebug, I realize that Jquery is not loaded, so `$` and `$.fn` is undefined.

My question is: why this schema of require.js is working with other jQuery plugins on the same project (like jquery cookie and others), but not with this, a jquery plugin with it's subplugins?

Comment: shouldnt that be `shim` instead of `shin`. Probably that should be the reason the dependencies are not followed and textExtTags is getting dowloaded before textExt sometime and you get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vishwanath said, only changing from "shin" to "shim" worked, like above:

```js
require.config({
  shim: {
    jquery: {
      exports: '$'
    },
  ...
```

Thanks!